# Rails 3 javascript sql query

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, geolocation

I have a question about querying the SQLite database in on of my Rails 3 app:

The purpose of the app is to locate the user and show a bunch of nearby locations.

The locations are stored in SQLite and I use JavaScript to geolocate the user and show his current position. Now that I have the Longitude and Latitude I want to check the database for nearby locations. How do I query the database with the long/lat javascript values?

I can only think of providing the data server side as .json and iterate trough it with javascript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a database directly from javascript (assuming you're in a browser), so your idea of providing the data server side with json is really as good an approach as any.

(Yes this would probably be better suited as a comment, but SO won't let me yet :p)